# Wordpress post-type create url rewriting

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

i create a new post-type in wordpress.
The new post-type is called work.

I want to customize the link when the user click "details button".
The link is `work/post_id/postname`

I have a trouble to connect the link to a details page.
The details page is called `single-work.php`
In my `functions.php` I write these rules:

```
add_action( 'init', 'wpse26388_rewrites_init' );
    function wpse26388_rewrites_init(){
    add_rewrite_rule( "work/([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)?$", "single-work.php", 'top' );
 }
```

But there is a trouble because when the user click the link, he sees the `index.php` and not `single-work.php`. How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a URL rewrite. WP will show the single work post by default using the `single-work.php` template.

Go to `Settings > Permalinks` and select `Custom Structure` there. Put this rule in the text input:

`/%post_id%/%postname%`

And save the settings.

This should work for you.

Comment: I setting this rules but when i click the link i see a index.php and not single-work.php .There are some thing that i customize? for exaples a .htaccess file or a option when i register my post-type?

Comment: Your htaccess might not be writable...